# How do I fix my missing dependency?

Tags: jgrasp

I installed jgrasp, a Java development environment. After installing it on Windows 10, I tried to start jgrasp up, which gave me this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\awt.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

The problem is, there is awt.dll in Java's bin file, but why isn't it recognizing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jGRASP is only a IDE tool. It will not work on its own. You need to install Java JDK which you can download here. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html. I will recommend intelleJ instead of jGRASP tho.t's nicer and more functional.

Answer (score 0):

Try jGRASP 2.0.4_02 which was just released. Most likely it will work. If not, install the latest Java 8 JDK and jGRASP will use that instead of Java 9 automatically.